# If statement in elmType wont work

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

Good Morning,
I'm trying to customize a column in my SharePoint in order to:

- send the user to a different action depending on the value of the column "status".

> Ex1.: the customize column will show a button that will start a flow
> if the status is "in
> Progress".
>
> Ex2.: the customized column will show a button that will send the user
> to the flow approval page if  other status.

- show a different text depending on the status.

So what I did is the following

```
`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "=if([$Status] == 'In progress', 'button','a')",
    "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"aa12ed12-ea81-4128-bf1c-2112d0d126b1\"}"
  },
    "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover",
      "target": "_blank",
    "href": "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if([$Status] == 'In progress', 'Flow','RedEye')"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if([$Status] == 'In progress', 'Start the Approval','See approval requests')"
    }
  ]
}`
```

As you can see the statement elmType wont work with an if statement. But it does what i need to do if i switch the elmType in "a" or "button". So how can I make it work?
Thanks in advance.
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I get the same result as yours. I tried to refer other columns value in elmtype element but failed. Looks like we cannot do any operators in the elmtype.

The elmType must be one of `div span a img svg button path`.

Besides, you could use `"debugMode": true` to turn on debug mode.